# How to use a button as a switch during loop (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, button

I am currently writing a program in VBA that will import data, parse it and export it as a CSV. Everything works perfectly fine, but I am trying to add a feature that allows the user to press a button in the middle of code to stop it after the next file.

My problem is this: I currently have my program set to run on an infinite loop checking a folder for files to parse. If there is a file in the folder, great. If not, skip the code. At the beginning of the code, I have a `DoEvents` command in order to keep the code from freezing, causing an infinite loop crash. However, this command doesn't seem to be picking up my button press on a sheet.

Here is what I have. When the user begins the program, it starts checking for files. In the meantime, however, it switches to a new sheet that has a button on it that is labeled "Stop" so that, hypothetically, it will stop the program after the current file is done. But nothing seems to happen when I click the button and wait- it just never recognizes it.

Here is the question I need solving- How can I have a button that will stop/pause the program during an infinite loop cycle? It works perfectly fine when it's just skipping the code during an empty folder state, but as soon as it begins parsing files it doesn't recognize the button press. Is there a way to do this using UserForms or even Form Buttons? If so, what is the best way to approach the problem?

My current code:

```
Sub automaticParsing()
isActive = True
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
varSrcPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("B2").Value
varDestPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C2").Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Buttons("ToggleButton").Caption = "Stop"
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Processing").Visible = True
Sheets("Processing").Activate
Sheets("UserMenu").Visible = False
Sheets("UserMenu2").Visible = False
On Error GoTo 0
While isActive = True
    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Trigger switch - button changes value of this range to "0"
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("A2").Value = "1" Then
        varNameOnly = Dir(varSrcPath)
        varGetFile = varSrcPath & varNameOnly
        'If the folder is empty, do not run code
        If varNameOnly = "" Then
            GoTo skipfile
        End If

        'Checks to see if file name had extension
        varTempBool = False
        For varTempItgr = 1 To Len(varGetFile)
            If Mid(varGetFile, varTempItgr, 1) = "." Then
                varTempBool = True
            End If
        Next
        If varTempBool = False Then varGetFile = varGetFile & "."
        varFileExtension = Mid(varGetFile, InStrRev(varGetFile, "."))

        'If file name didn't have an extension, first argument outputs incorrectly
        If varTempBool = True Then
            varTrueNameOnly = Left(varNameOnly, Len(varNameOnly) - Len(varFileExtension))
        Else
            varTrueNameOnly = varNameOnly
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("Processing").Visible = True
        On Error GoTo 0
        Sheets("Processing").Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Clears tabs
        Call ClearTabs
        'Determines file type and runs another giant section of code far too large for this post based on that
        Call RunMacro

        If Workbooks("TableBook").Worksheets("test").Range("A" & Workbooks("TableBook").Worksheets("test").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 59000 Then
            Call exportTable
        End If

        'As long as the file wasn't already moved, move it to the destination path
        If varAlreadyMoved = False Then
            Name varGetFile As varDestPath & varNameOnly
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'Checks to see if any open workbook is correctly named, and if so, deletes it.
        For varTempItgr = 1 To Workbooks.Count
            If Workbooks(varTempItgr).Name = varTrueNameOnly & ".CSV" Then
                Workbooks(varTrueNameOnly).Close
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        isActive = False
    End If
skipfile:
    Wend
ThisWorkbook.Activate
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("UserMenu").Visible = True
Sheets("UserMenu2").Visible = False
Sheets("Processing").Visible = False
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

If you have any more questions about the code, I'd be happy to inform you.

Comment: Can you show your code? It should be possible to help you, but we need to see how you are implementing this loop.

Comment: Usually you would have the button set a global variable to `True` and within the loop you would look for this state and exit the loop  `if gAbort then exit do ..`

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry about that. Let me know if you have any questions on the code.

Comment: @AlexK. that's not solving the problem. I actually need it to only stop after the current file is done, plus VBA won't actually register the clicking of the button while the code is parsing for some odd reason. Even by adding "DoEvents" it won't register the click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an infinite loop use [Application.OnTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165(v=office.15).aspx) to schedule the execution of your folder scanning code. This example code will scan the folder 5 seconds after the last "processing" was completed and cancel operation if the button is clicked:

Declare global variables in a Module:

```
Dim bStopProcessing as Boolean 'for cancelling the process
Dim nextScheduledScanTime as Date 'time at which to call scanFolderForChanges() again
```

Initialize `bStopProcessing` and call the `scanFolderForChanges()` subroutine in the separate macro that begins the whole process:

```
Sub startScanning()
    'calling this subroutine will begin continuous scanning
    bStopProcessing = False
    scanFolderForChanges
End Sub
```

Folder scanning subroutine:

```
Sub scanFolderForChanges()
    'if [btnStopProcessing] was clicked, stop processing.
    If bStopProcessing Then Exit Sub
    '...
    '<folder scanning and processing code goes here>
    '...
    If Not bStopProcessing Then
        'store the scheduled time so we can cancel it if the workbook is closed
        nextScheduledScanTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        'schedule the next call to this subroutine (5 seconds from now)
        Application.OnTime nextScheduledScanTime, "scanFolderForChanges"
    End If
End Sub
```

Within the stop button's click event:

```
Private Sub btnStopProcessing_Click()
    bStopProcessing = True
End Sub
```

Within the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'prevent the scheduled procedure from being called after this workbook is closed
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime nextScheduledScanTime, "scanFolderForChanges", , False
End Sub
```

Passing `False` as the "Schedule" parameter tells the `OnTime()` method to cancel the scheduled subroutine call that matches the first two parameters. This line could also be written:

```
    Application.OnTime nextScheduledScanTime, "scanFolderForChanges", Schedule:=False
```

Comment: My only problem with that is that is that every file that I parse takes different amounts of time - usually somewhere between 50 seconds and a minute. But I don't want to limit the amount of time that it has to finish parsing in case I get a large file that takes longer. As it is, I'm looking at 18+ hours to parse 1,000 files, which is a fraction of what I'll be doing in the long run. Would this solution still be valid?

Comment: @jaysoncopes I've updated the answer to prevent execution of the folder scans until the code is not "in process". With this code you could schedule the folder scanning to occur much more frequently.

Comment: Thank you - I'll try that next time I get the chance. Thanks for the timely responses!

Comment: Ok, so I had to unmark this as an answer because it seems to be skipping all of my files (this is the first chance I've had to try out your code.) - Every couple of second it moves a file, but it doesn't actually run the parsing code that it should. It's almost as though every X seconds it stops whatever it started and restarts.

Comment: @jaysoncopes This answer allows you to "use a button as a switch during loop (VBA)" please mark it as the answer and create a new question that is specific to your current problem including all of the code you are having a problem with.

Comment: My apologies, I had a malfunction in my code causing it to skip files. However, now I'm getting a "Cannot run the macro 'automaticParsing()'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled" error. What does this mean?

Comment: @jaysoncopes That error is displayed when the `Application.OnTime()` method cannot find the macro name. The macro cannot be declared as `Private` and must be available when the scheduled execution time is reached. This can also happen if the workbook that contains the macro has been closed but Excel is still open. The error message is benign but there are ways to prevent it from happening.

Comment: So how does your example work? Your example shows the `Application.OnTime()` method running the subroutine that it is currently in. I implemented your code directly into the code that I provided above (AKA not declared `Private`) and I'm still getting this answer. I thought you edited your response to "prevent execution of the folder scans until the code is not 'in process'"?

Comment: @jaysoncopes I have revised the answer. Now the OnTime() method will not be called until the current process is done. Also, if the workbook is closed the scheduled procedure call will be cancelled.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need to introduce multi-threading into your code. That way, your loop can check the state of a Boolean value at the start of each loop, and if it meets the criteria, it continues. The second thread (for the button press) could change the state of the variable so that when the loop reaches it the next time, the condition is not met and the program stops.